# How to save/load the whole internal states (not the parameters) of the BackgroundSubtractors, OpenCVSharp?

Tags: c#, opencv, background-subtraction

I have successfully used OpenCVSharp, specifically the BackgroundSubtractorGMG, BackgroundSubtractorKNN, and BackgroundSubtractorMOG2, to perform background subtraction on images. However, when attempting to save the trained model, I have found that I can only save and load the parameters used to configure it!

Do you have any suggestions on how I can save the entire model with its learned state for future use? If there isn't a direct way to achieve this, is it feasible to make modifications to the library to enable such functionality?

Tried to use the ".Save" function that only saves the parameters!
Expected to be able to save the whole model, with its internal states.

Comment: [crosspost](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266159): https://forum.opencv.org/t/how-to-save-load-the-whole-internal-states-not-the-parameters-of-the-backgroundsubtractors-opencvsharp/15447